# Jquery DialogBox positiong issues (stuck on top left)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-1.9

I have been having an issue with the positioning of a dialog box.

I am using classic ASP or VBScript along with jquery-ui-1.10.2 and jquery-1.9.1.js

My dialog box is working just fine except for the positioning. It seems to be stuck in the top left corner of the page regardless of what I change. I have added a position, set center = true, tried to modify the styling, and other little tweaks but nothing seems to work. I am at a loss here and was wondering if anyone else has run into a similar issue, thanks.

When I downloaded JQuery UI I made sure everything was checked.

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<td id="Comments" height="39" colspan="1">
</td>
</table>

<div id="dialog-message" title="Important information">
    <p style="text-align:center;"> Message regarding this content </p>
    <br/>
    <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
    <p>Subject: <input type="text" id="subject" />
    <br/> <br/>
    Body: <input type="text" id="question" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dialog-message").hide()
    } 
    );
$("#Comments").click(function() {
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 500,
        }
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: HAve you included the CSS that comes with your plugin?

Comment: Yes I have. Sorry, forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up the code solves the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-message").hide();
    $("#Comments").click(function() {
            $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 400,
                height: 500
            });
    });
});
```

Here's a [**working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/5LfL5/9/)

Comment: @shenn, has this answer been able to help you in any way?